# Regex match with 2 special characters or more - PowerShell script

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to match a regex for a PowerShell script. The regex must match on a minimum of 2 special characters, minimum length 20. Here is some examples:

```
[string]$regex = "(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=[^#!@%^*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:<>,.?\/].*?[#!@%^*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:<>,.?\/]{2})[A-Za-z0-9#!@%^*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:<>,.?\/]{20,42}"

"Mypassword123#Mypassword123#" -match $regex
False (desired result is true..)

"Mypassword123#Mypassword123##" -match $regex
True (all OK)
```

What is incorrect in the first example, the 2 `#` characters should match?

Comment: You’re saying there has to be 2 symbols back to back, not in total.

Comment: That happens due to `{2}` after ``[#!@%^*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:<>,.?\/]``, remove it. But you also need to use `-cmatch` and add `^` at the start and `$` at the end. Well, ``^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=(?:.*[#!@%^*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:<>,.?\/]){2})[A-Za-z0-9#!@%^*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:<>,.?\/]{20,42}$`` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a single, mind-bending regex, I suggest taking a more algorithmic approach, which - while more verbose - is easier to understand and therefore to maintain:

```
# Sample password.
$pass = 'Mypassword123#Mypassword123#'

# Analyze the characters.
$specialCharCount = 0; $hasInvalidChars = $false
switch -Regex ($pass.ToCharArray()) {
  '[a-z0-9]' { continue }
  '[#!@%^*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:<>,.?/]' { ++$specialCharCount }
  default { $hasInvalidChars = $true; break }
}

$valid = -not $hasInvalidChars -and 
         $pass.Length -ge 20 and $pass.Length -le 42 -and 
         $specialCharCount -ge 2
```

Note:

- There's no restriction on which characters can occur where.
- As in your attempt, two special characters are sufficient *even if they're the same* - it would take a bit more work to ensure that at least two *different* special chars. are present.
- PowerShell's regex matching is case-*insensitive* by default, so `[a-z]` implicitly also includes `[A-Z]`.